# PySerial write timed out -- how much data went through?

Tags: python, sockets, timeout, pyserial

I have two applications interacting over a TCP/IP connection; now I need them to be able to interact over a serial connection as well.

There are a few differences between socket IO and serial IO that make porting less trivial than I hoped for.

One of the differences is about the semantics of send/write timeouts and the assumptions an application may make about the amount of data successfully passed down the connection. Knowing this amount the application also knows what leftover data it needs to transmit later should it choose so.

### Socket.send

A call like socket.send(string) may produce the following results:

1. The entire string has been accepted by the TCP/IP stack, and the
   length of the string is returned.
2. A part of the string has been accepted by the TCP/IP stack, and the
   length of that part is returned. The application may transmit the
   rest of the string later.
3. A socket.timeout exception is raised if the socket is configured to
   use timeouts and the sender overwhelms the connection with data.
   This means (if I understand it correctly) that *no* bytes of the
   string have been accepted by the TCP/IP stack and hence the
   application may try to send the entire string later.
4. A socket.error exception is raised because of some issues with the
   connection.

### PySerial.Serial.write

The PySerial API documentation says the following about Serial.write(string):

```
write(data)
  Parameters:   
    data – Data to send.
  Returns:  
    Number of bytes written.
  Raises 
    SerialTimeoutException:
      In case a write timeout is configured for the port and the time is exceeded.

  Changed in version 2.5: Write returned None in previous versions.
```

This spec leaves a few questions uncertain to me:

1. In which circumstances may "write(data)" return fewer bytes written
   than the length of the data? Is it only possible in the non-blocking
   mode (writeTimeout=0)?
2. If I use a positive writeTimeout and the SerialTimeoutException is
   raised, how do I know how many bytes went into the connection?

I also observe some behaviors of serial.write that I did not expect.

The test tries sending a long string over a slow connection. The sending port uses 9600,8,N,1 and no flow control. The receiving port is open too but no attempts to read data from it are being made.

1. If the writeTimeout is positive but not large enough the sender expectedly
   gets the SerialTimeoutException.
2. If the writeTimeout is set large enough the sender expectedly gets all data written
   successfully (the receiver does not care to read, neither do we).
3. If the writeTimeout is set to None, the sender *unexpectedly* gets the SerialTimeoutException
   instead of blocking until all data goes down the connection. Am I missing something?

I do not know if that behavior is typical.
In case that matters, I experiment with PySerial on Windows 7 64-bit using two USB-to-COM adapters connected via a null-modem cable; that setup seems to be operational as two instances of Tera Term can talk to each other over it.

It would be helpful to know if people handle serial write timeouts in any way other than aborting the connection and notifying the user of the problem.

Since I currently do not know the amount of data written before the timeout has occurred, I am thinking of a workaround using non-blocking writes and maintaining the socket-like timeout semantics myself above that level. I do not expect this to be a terrifically efficient solution (:-)), but luckily my applications exchange relatively infrequent and short messages so the performance should be within the acceptable range.

[EDITED]

### A closer look at non-blocking serial writes

I wrote a simple program to see if I understand how the non-blocking write works:

```
import serial

p1 = serial.Serial("COM11") # My USB-to-COM adapters appear at these high port numbers
p2 = serial.Serial("COM12")

message = "Hello! " * 10
print "%d bytes in the whole message: %r" % (len(message), message)

p1.writeTimeout = 0 # enabling non-blocking mode
bytes_written = p1.write(message)
print "Written %d bytes of the message: %r" % (bytes_written, message[:bytes_written])  

print "Receiving back %d bytes of the message" % len(message)
message_read_back = p2.read(len(message))
print "Received back %d bytes of the message: %r" % (len(message_read_back), message_read_back) 

p1.close()
p2.close()
```

The output I get is this:

> 70 bytes in the whole message: 'Hello! Hello! Hello! Hello! Hello! Hello! Hello! Hello! Hello! Hello! '
>   Written 0 bytes of the message: ''
>   Receiving back 70 bytes of the message
>   Received back 70 bytes of the message: 'Hello! Hello! Hello! Hello! Hello! Hello! Hello! Hello! Hello! Hello! '

I am very confused: the sender thinks no data was sent yet the receiver got it all. I must be missing something very fundamental here...

Any comments / suggestions / questions are very welcome!

Answer (score 1):

Since it isn't documented, let's look at the source code. I only looked at the [POSIX](http://sourceforge.net/p/pyserial/code/461/tree/trunk/pyserial/serial/serialposix.py#l479) and [Win32](http://sourceforge.net/p/pyserial/code/461/tree/trunk/pyserial/serial/serialwin32.py#l253) implementations, but it's pretty obvious that on at least those two platforms:

1. There are *no* circumstances when `write(data)` may return fewer bytes written than the length of the data, timeout or otherwise; it always either returns the full `len(data)`, or raises an exception.
2. If you use a positive `writeTimeout` and the `SerialTimeoutException` is raised, there is no way at all to tell how many bytes were sent.

In particular, on POSIX, the number of bytes sent so far is only stored on a local variable that's lost as soon as the exception is raised; on Windows, it just does a single overlapped `WriteFile` and raises an exception for anything but a successful "wrote everything".

I assume that you care about at least one of those two platforms. (And if not, you're probably not writing cross-platform code, and can look at the one platform you do care about.) So, there is no direct solution to your problem.

If the workaround you described is acceptable, or a different one (like writing exactly one byte at a time—which is probably even less efficient, but maybe simpler), do that.

Alternatively, you will have to edit the `write` implementations you care about (whether you do this by forking the package and editing your fork, monkeypatching `Serial.write` at runtime, or just writing a `serial_write` function and calling `serial_write(port, data)` instead of `port.write(data)` in your script) to provide the information you want.

That doesn't look too hard. For example, in the POSIX version, you just have to stash `len(data)-t` somewhere before either of the `raise writeTimeoutError` lines. You could stick it in an attribute of the `Serial` object, or pass it as an extra argument to the exception constructor. (Of course if you're trying to write a cross-platform program, and you don't know all of the platforms well enough to write the appropriate implementations, that isn't likely to be a good answer.)

And really, given that it's not that hard to implement what you want, you might want to add a feature request (ideally with a patch) on the pyserial tracker.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed comment, it helps! (I do not yet have enough reputation to up-vote your comment, sorry :-|)


I now set off for the workaround. Good point of making a feature request to the PySerial developers. I am unlikely to prepare a patch myself now; not until I get more expertise in serial comms.  


Regarding the fact #1 in your post: can't Serial.write return fewer bytes if writeTimeout is 0? The code in serialwin32.py seems to raise writeTimeoutError only if self._writeTimeout != 0. A program in my [edited] question tries to see what happens; I am baffled with its output.

Comment: @V.P.: From a quick scan of the docs (start at MSDN's [`WriteFile`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365747(v=vs.85).aspx) and follow the links for both communications devices and overlapped I/O), I think the only outcomes are timeout, error, explicit cancel, or writing everything. But I could be wrong; you should probably read the docs more carefully and/or do some tests (calling `WriteFile` directly via win32api, ctypes, cython, whatever)…

Comment: Thanks for the pointers, I might have to go along this path. I only want to make sure that I won't be inventing a wheel. I also would be glad to know what are the dominating practices of using serial write timeouts other than not using them at all or treating them as critical errors. Does anyone ever use them? Any mature project that uses them heavily?

Comment: @V.P.: Sorry, I don't really know where to look, and I can't find any pyserial community list or wiki or anything, so… maybe contact the author?